# Anylogic: duplicate basic model

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have created a basic model in Anylogic (model name: Basic & java package: basic). This basic model represents our current production. Now I want to simulate different optimization concepts and adjust the basic model accordingly. In order to keep my basic model, I have saved the basic model in a new file. For this I changed the model name to basic1 and also the java package to basic1. However, Anylogic crashes every time during this saving process. Does anyone know what the reason is and how I can manage to save my basic model in a new (independent) file?

Comment: Do you copy the whole folder?

Comment: No, I right-click in Anylogic on my model (projects view) and select "save as". Then i change the model name and the java package

Comment: Copy-paste the whole folder. Then change the file and package name. It should be working (if this is the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is really related to saving files, here is the method I am sure that works (it might be that your problem is somewhere else). I always do it as following:

1. Copy paste the whole folder.

[image]

2.Change the AnyLogic file name.

[image]

3. Open the model and change the package name.

[image]

This will create an independent model for you.